# System freezes at login, in recovery mode and in TTYs

Tags: linux-mint, boot, nvidia

**Summary:**

After updating drivers and installing Ubuntu Studio on top of *Linux Mint 20.2* (Uma), my computer freezes at login no matter what I'm trying.

**Backstory:**

After realizing my computer is not compatible with Windows 11 and being tired of the OS in general, I switched to Linux. I tried a couple of distros and decided to go with Linux Mint. I tried Zorin OS, but I kept getting this same error when trying to log in after installation. I thought it was an issue with Zorin and went with Linux Mint. After I installed it, it ran smoothly, and did what I needed it to do. I updated the drivers to use the NVIDIA driver, and that ran smoothly as well. The issue popped back up when I installed Ubuntu Studio. I installed it, and it asked me to restart.

**The issue:**

When it gets to the login page, everything froze. The mouse, keyboard, cursor...everything froze. I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to restart the system when it's frozen, but no other commands or keys will change the frozen screen. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> seems to run a command to restart the system, which pops up briefly before the computer restarts. So, it seems like the system still listens to some commands.

**What I've tried:**

- Changing the `quiet splash` in the GRUB editor to `nomodeset`. **Result:** Still freezes at login
- Run in "recovery mode". **Result:** It freezes when the options window pulls up and won't allow me to select an option.
- Hitting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (F1-F6) command to try to use a command prompt. **Result:** Freezes even with the console up.
- Run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> once frozen. **Result:** Nothing happens. It stays frozen.

**Specs:**

- **CPU:** Intel i7-7700HQ Kaby Lake-H Mobile
- **GPU:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with 6GB GDDR5
- **Display:** 15.6 FHD 1080P 120Hz AUO IPS with G-SYNC
- **Video Out:** 1x HDMI 2.0b, 1x Mini DisplayPort 1.4
- **Storage:** 256GB M.2 PCIe NVMe SSD, 1TB 5400RPM Seagate SATA
- **Memory:** 16GB 2400MHz DDR4 SO-DIMM’s (8GBx2) 2 Slots
- **Wireless:** Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
- **Ethernet:** Intel i219-V 10/100/1000 Controller, 1x RJ45 Connector
- **Bluetooth:** Bluetooth 4.2
- **USB:** 3x USB 3.0 Type A, 1x USB 3.1 Type C
- **Webcam:** Full HD 1920x1080, Integrated Digital Mic
- **Audio:** Realtek ALC 255, Stereo Speakers, 2x 3.5mm (1x Headphone Jack, 1x 3.5mm Mic)

I'm really at a loss of knowing how to fix this. I think looking at logs might help if there is a log of what happens when it freezes. I'm not sure where to go for that. I don't know where to start looking. I also have read that a common issue is with the NVIDIA card and Linux. If that's the case, how do I resolve that? I believe the proper drivers are installed. I've also read that the packages might not have been properly installed, and I would have to run `dpkg`, but I can't get to the command line without it freezing. I have a version of Linux Mint on a USB that I am currently using, but I'm not sure where I should go to change packages or drivers or whatever I need to do to fix this.

Can someone point me in the right direction? How can I use the command line when it's frozen? Can I access it before it logs in? What should I be looking for?

*Note: The Ubuntu crowd kicked me off their forum and told me to come here since it has to deal with Linux Mint and Zorin and not Ubuntu specifically.*

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to check the log files is to run the live Linux. You can mount your system then.
May be better for you this : https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-boot-into-linux-command-line

Comment: I can run a live USB of Linux that allows me to look at all of the log files. I'm just not sure I know what I'm looking for.

Comment: 1st of all, check the /var/log/dmesg , /var/log/syslog and /var/log/Xorg.0.log.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I've reinstalled Linux Mint and have run into the same issue repeatedly.

Comment: I hit similar problem. The new kernels and the old nvidia driver can not work together correctly. Same computer with centos 7 works well with 4 monitor, with mint 20, is'nt.